# while creating RAW_SOCKET error like Operation not permitted

Tags: c, sockets, voip

in my android application i want to create RAW SOCKET but when i try to create it by following code it gives error like Operation not permitted.

```
int sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_UDP);
if(sd < 0)
{
    ortp_warning("socket() error %s",getSocketError());
    // If something wrong just exit
    //exit(-1);
}
else
{
    ortp_warning("socket() - Using SOCK_RAW socket and UDP protocol is OK.\n");
}
```

how can i solve it.??

Answer (score 5):

You must have root privileges to create a raw socket. It is a privileged action; run as sudo or root.

Comment: its like Operation not permitted

Comment: If you are root, then you can do that. How are you running the application?

Answer (score 1):

try setting  CAP_NET_RAW  and cap_net_admin capability to your application.
Details could be found at http://linux.die.net/man/7/capabilities

```
 # setcap cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin=eip APPLICATION_PATH
```

Comment: my application is android  app in which use native code and i have to create raw socket in c code.so after building app i set  both capabilities but still its give error like operation not permitted.for this have i  to root my android device.????

Comment: No you dont have to root your device ,but your application should have <uses-permission android:name ="android.permission.INTERNET"/> in manifest file.

Comment: this permission is already set but still not creating raw socket.

Comment: What permissions does your executable has?try to use chmod and change permissions for execution.

Comment: 1.sudo chown root:root <app>,2 sudo chmod u+s <app> for  these permission i have set.